# Using 3x UITabBar Icons for iOS 7 With Some Strange Results Compared to iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have an existing iOS 7 app which works really well on the iPhone with iOS 7. I'm now building up my app for iOS 8 with Xcode 6. The app is a basic UITabBar where each Tab is a UITableViewController.

Because I am developing for the iPhone 6 Plus, I am using 3x icons from PixelLove (http://www.pixellove.com) in the Storyboard. I am still supporting iOS 7 on the iPhone 5s, etc (for the time being) and because I'm using Storyboard to bring in the 3x icons, I'm getting some extremely strange results on an iOS 7 device.

**iOS 7 Tab Bar Icons**

[image]

**iOS 8 Tab Bar Icons**

[image]

I have tested this on physical devices, not just the Simulator and it's still occurring.

How can I set the original tab bar images for the iOS 7 devices compared to the iOS 8?

Any guidance on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: What's the images names? Can u add some code if u have so?

Comment: thanks @gran33 - the image names are for example email@3x.png, calendar@3x.png, timer@3x.png, etc. The previous images were called calendar@2x.png, etc. I can upload any code, but unfortunately, I'm not sure what to upload because this was all created in Storyboard. I went to the Storyboard and added in the images from the inspector view.

Answer (score 2):

U need to name your images like this:

```
calendar.png -> 320x480

calendar@2x.png -> 640x960

calendar-568h@2x.png -> 640x1136

calendar-375h@2x.png -> 750x1334

calendar-736h@3x.png -> 1242x2208
```

As u comment on your question, U name your image `calendar@3x.png` and u should name it like `calendar-736h@3x.png`

Comment: thanks so much @gran33 and that makes sense. Does that apply to the tab bar icons though? I've used that naming convention for the launch images, but I just wanted to check if that actually applies the Tab Bar icons? According to the HIG (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) - the tab bar icons for the 6 plus need to be 75x75 compared to 50x50. I just need to understand how to distinguish between the old & new tab bar icons for the iPhone 6 Plus only and show the old on other devices.

Comment: It apply for any image resource u have in your project.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Comment: Thanks gran - that doesn't work because I'm adding the images in the Storyboard.. If I were adding the images in code, I could get this working, but the Tab Bar Icons (UITabBar) are messed up on iOS 7.. Because I'm adding the calendar-736h@3x.png but any devices on iOS 7  still have the gigantic images.

Comment: U should add the image name in the storyboard as the original name **calendar.png**